# Any Rails plugin to add comments about each column in ActiveRecord migration files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to insert COMMENT, which is part of SQL the command, in my migration files.

[As far as I know, I can add COMMENT to each table and column.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

I can't remember a plugin name that lets me to write as follows:

```
    t.string  :name, :comment => "A user's fullname"
    t.string  :label, :comment => "name of color"
    t.text  :value, :comment => "self intro"
    t.integer  :position, :comment => "1 is left, 2 is right"
```

And that statement magically is translated into SQL, which is like

```
create table test (
  name varchar(255) not null COMMENT 'blahblah',
  label varchar(255) null COMMENT 'hahaha'
  text varchar(255) not null,
  position int(11)
);
```

Does anybody know the plug in name?

---

- I'm not looking for [Annotate Models plugins](http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2006/02/annotate_models.html) by Dave Thomas. What I mean by comments is inside MySQL queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any plugin that will accomplish what you're asking for.  You *might* be able to hack in what you want by looking at `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ColumnDefinition`.  (See `active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb`.)

As you can see the `Struct` defines the various column options (like `:limit` and `:default`.)  You could extended that struct with a `:comment` and then modify `#to_sql` to generate the required SQL.  You would also need to modify `TableDefinition#column` to set the `:comment` attribute.

The following has been tested and works (for MySQL):

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class ColumnDefinition
      attr_accessor :comment

      def to_sql_with_comment
        column_sql = to_sql_without_comment
        return column_sql if comment.nil?
       "#{column_sql} COMMENT '#{base.quote_string(comment)}'"
      end

      alias_method_chain :to_sql, :comment
    end

    class TableDefinition
      # Completely replaces (and duplicates the existing code, but there's
      # no place to really hook into the middle of this.)
      def column(name, type, options = {})
        column = self[name] || ColumnDefinition.new(@base, name, type)
        if options[:limit]
          column.limit = options[:limit]
        elsif native[type.to_sym].is_a?(Hash)
          column.limit = native[type.to_sym][:limit]
        end
        column.precision = options[:precision]
        column.scale = options[:scale]
        column.default = options[:default]
        column.null = options[:null]
        column.comment = options[:comment]
        @columns << column unless @columns.include? column
        self
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is amazing. I haven't test your code, either. But I'll take your approach.

Comment: Which part isn't working? Did you add any logging to see if the methods are being called?

Comment: It didn't give me any error. But when I log into MySQL and type `show create table users`, it doesn't show `COMMENT` stuff. I haven't add any logging, I'll try adding some.

Comment: Where have you defined `to_sql_without_comment`?

Comment: The `alias_method_chain` defines the `to_sql_without_comment` method as being an alias to the _old_ `to_sql` method. See the documentation from `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Module`.

Comment: @TK There was a spelling mistake in the example code. I've fixed it and confirmed that it does work when I placed the above code in `config/initializers/comment_migration.rb`. They only _gotcha_ is that the above code does not escape single-quotes, so your "A user's full name" generates a parse error. That should be easy enough to fix.

Comment: @TK And I've now updated the code to quote the comment string correctly, so the "A user's full name" is accepted and generates correct SQL.

Answer (score 6):

Shameless plug - there is now a '[migration_comments](https://github.com/pinnymz/migration_comments)' gem that works for commenting MySQL, SQLite, and PostgreSQL.  It supports Rails 2.3 and higher at this time.  It also works together with the [annotate](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) gem (v2.5.0 or higher) to generate these comments in your Model/Fixture/Spec files.

Answer (score 1):

After a failure getting migration_comments gem to work for Oracle, I just tried the following with activerecord -v 4.1.1 and the comment was added correctly.
So no more need for extra gems.

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table TABLENAME do |table|
      table.column :status, :integer, :comment => "Keeps status for this signal"
      table.column :rowversion, :integer, :comment => "Increments with each change of this record"
      etc..
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 5, you can now directly add comments to your migration without using any plugin.

You can add comments for table, column and index.

You can view these comments in schema.rb plus from DBA tool.

Example :

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products, comment: 'Products table' do |t|
      t.string :name, comment: 'Name of the product'
      t.string :barcode, comment: 'Barcode of the product'
      t.string :description, comment: 'Product details'
      t.float :msrp, comment: 'Maximum Retail Price'
      t.float :our_price, comment: 'Selling price'

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :products, :name, name: 'index_products_on_name', unique: true, comment: 'Index used to lookup product by name.'
  end
end
```

Note : This is only supported for PostgreSQL and MySQL.